# New rule depending on calendar event for shared mailbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

We have a shared outlook mailbox for a technical support group.

There are 3 members inside the support group and each of them take turn to handle support tickets.

The member that needs to check the mailbox is determined by events in shared calendar.

> Instead of having 1 folder for all emails, I would like to have 1 folder per support member (so three in that case) and move the email to the right folder according to who’s the one handling the tickets this week.

How can I achieve something like this? Do I need a rule or is there anything else to do that kind of work ?

Thanks!